# Converting annual survival rate to daily mortality probability

Tags: biostatistics, ecology

In a peer-reviewed paper, I came across the following conversion:
Yearly survival rate -> 0.70
The authors have calculated the daily probability of death using

> (1 - 0.70^(1/365.25)) = 0.000976

The way I would calculate for the daily probability of death:
Yearly survival rate -> 0.70
Therefore yearly mortality rate -> 0.30
Using the equation,

> probability (p) = 1 - exp(-rt)

where: r = instantaneous rate, provided that it is constant over the period of interest (t) (Reference: Briggs A, Sculpher M, Claxton K. Decision Modelling for Health Economic Evaluation. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2006:51), I get a daily mortality probability of 0.00082.

I would like to know if my understanding is flawed.
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you check your answer?  If you're correct, then $(1 - 0.00082)^{365.25}$ (or, if you prefer, $\exp(365.25 * \log(1 - 0.00082)),$ which will be the same) had better equal $0.70.$

Comment: Thanks @whuber. Could you point to the flaw in my approach?

Comment: You haven't disclosed your calculations, leaving us nothing to point to except the wrong value.

Comment: Daily probability of death = 1-exp(-0.3*1/365.25) = 0.00082

Comment: @ABel In your calculation, you put in $r = .3$ as the instantaneous rate, but it's not an instantaneous rate. 0.3 in a year don't survive. The instantaneous yearly rate would solve $.3 = 1 - \exp(-r_{\mathrm{per year}})$ or if you wish to work in units of days, the instantaneous daily rate would solve $.3 = 1 - \exp(-r_{\mathrm{per day}}365.25)$

Comment: @MatthewGunn Thank you for your help! Now I know: 1) Annual survival rate = 0.7, so annual mortality rate = 1 - 0.7 = 0.3. 2) Converting 0.3 to instantaneous rate using equation: [1 + (rate / number of periods)]^ number of periods - 1 gives (1+(0.3 / 365.25))^365.25 -1 = 0.34969. 3) Using this instantaneous rate in the equation for probability (p) = 1 - exp(-rt) gives 0.00096!